# Selecting any date in DateEdit1 and display the 18th day in DateEdit2

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, windows-forms-designer

Can someone help me, it is possible to choose any Date in DateEdit1 then display the 18th day of the month(selected month in DateEdit1) in DateEdit2 in VB.net. Not Working on mine. Thank you for helping me. I would preferred other source code if you have.

OBTAForTheMonthDateEdit is the DateEdit1,
OBTADeadlineDateEdit is the DateEdit2

```
Private Sub OBTADeadlineDateEdit_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OBTADeadlineDateEdit.TextChanged
        Dim binding = New Binding("Value", OBTAForTheMonthDateEdit, "Value")
        AddHandler binding.Format, AddressOf FormatDate
        OBTAForTheMonthDateEdit.DataBindings.Add(binding)
    End Sub

    Private Sub FormatDate(sender As Object, e As ConvertEventArgs)
        OBTADeadlineDateEdit.Text = $"{OBTAForTheMonthDateEdit.Value.AddMonths(3).ToShortDateString()}"
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Get date parts (year and month) from datepicker1 and assign this date with day=18 to datepicker2. Use function new dateTime to create it. note : I add 1 month offset if selected date day > 17.

```
  Private Sub OBTAForTheMonthDateEdit_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OBTAForTheMonthDateEdit.ValueChanged
    Dim dt As Date = OBTAForTheMonthDateEdit.Value
    If dt.Day > 17 Then
        If dt.Month = 12 Then  'if december restart to january, year +1
            OBTADeadlineDateEdit.Value = New DateTime(dt.Year + 1, 1, 18)
        Else
            OBTADeadlineDateEdit.Value = New DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month + 1, 18)
        End If
    Else
        OBTADeadlineDateEdit.Value = New DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 18)
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit: when december day > 17 jump to year+1 january

Comment: Thank you but if I select datepicker1 december (datepicker1 > 17) 2022, it appears error, it says, System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.', I can't select previous year. if datepicker1 greater than 17.

Comment: Indeed I forgot this edge effect: I edited answer to fix it.